# calculating the sum over products of object attributes in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I have objects called 'order' which have an attributes 'product.price' and 'quantity'. I want to calculate the total cost of all orders. I am passing all orders as a list into the template and I would like to see jinja2 do the work.

If I just want to calculate the sum over all prices I can do

```
${{ '%0.2f'| format(orders | sum(attribute='product.price')) }}
```

but how can I add the multiplication with the quantity attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure there's a way to do it in one line. This could work though:

```html
{% set totals = [] %}

{% for order in orders %}
  {% if totals.append(order.product.price * order.quantity %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

${{ '%0.2f' | format(totals | sum) }}
```